# Go back to previous links while using tab

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

Lately I've been trying to use my keyboard as much as possible to increase efficiency. I know that you can use tab to go through the various links in the browser or even in any window opened in general. The only, thing about using tabs is that it goes through each item sequentially. This means that if you miss an item that you wanted to access, you have to keep hitting tab until you get back to this same item. I was just wondering if anyone knew of a way to go back (i.e. tab backwards)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will generally take the focus "back a tab point" - so back to the last focus point the tab took you from, but it is application dependent.

Comment: Thank you this does answer my question. Also, I don't know whether this is possible or not but, do you know of a way to start the tab at a particular location instead of starting from the top left corner of the window. Also, if this is not possible, does anybody know how to skip links while you're tabbing?

Comment: @user77037, You can **click** near a 'Tab-able' element and then press `Tab` to have the focus move there.